# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.testing.nosetester'

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, importerror, nose

I was using the Decision Tree and this error was raised. The same situation appeared when I used Back Propagation. How can I solve it?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
a = np.test()
f = open('E:/lgdata.csv')
data = pd.read_csv(f,index_col = 'id')

x = data.iloc[:,10:12].as_matrix().astype(int)
y = data.iloc[:,9].as_matrix().astype(int)

from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier as DTC
dtc = DTC(criterion='entropy')
dtc.fit(x,y)
x=pd.DataFrame(x) 

from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
with open('tree.dot','w') as f1:
    f1 = export_graphviz(dtc, feature_names = x.columns, out_file = f1)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<ipython-input-40-4359c06ae1f0>", line 1, in <module>
>     runfile('C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/lib/site-packages/scipy/_lib/_numpy_compat.py', wdir='C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/lib/site-packages/scipy/_lib')
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 710, in runfile
>     execfile(filename, namespace)
>   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 101, in execfile
>     exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>   File "C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/lib/site-packages/scipy/_lib/_numpy_compat.py", line 9, in <module>
>     from numpy.testing.nosetester import import_nose
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.testing.nosetester'

Answer (score 67):

This is happening due to a version incompatibility between `numpy` and `scipy`. `numpy` in its latest versions have deprecated `numpy.testing.nosetester`.

### Replicating the issue

```
pip install numpy==1.18 # > 1.18
pip install scipy<=0.19.0 # <= 0.19
```

and

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier as DTC
```

Triggers the error.

### Fixing the error

Upgrade your `scipy` to a higher version.

```
pip install numpy==1.18
pip install scipy==1.1.0
pip install scikit-learn==0.21.3
```

But not limited to this. By upgrading the above libraries to the latest stable, you should be able to get rid of this error.

Comment: also with import shap
we have to first: pip3 install scipy==1.1.0

Comment: It started working after upgrading following packages to latest version (pip install <packagename>  --upgrade)
    1. numpy
    2. scipy 
    3.seaborn

Answer (score 14):

I needed to upgrade scipy

`pip3 install -U scipy`

Answer (score 6):

I was facing the same error while using lexnlp package 
Got it fixed by installing:

```
scipy==1.4.1
pandas==0.23.4    
numpy==1.18.1
lexnlp==0.2.7.1
```

(Only install lexnlp if know you're explicitly using it in your project and you know what you're doing)

Answer (score 5):

I solved this by:

```
pip uninstall numpy
pip install numpy == 1.17.0
```

and using:

```
from numpy.testing import rundocs
```

Answer (score 4):

I also faced same issue while loading the model and fixed by upgrading below libraries

```
pip install -U numpy
pip install -U pandas
pip install -U scipy
```

Answer (score 2):

try installing numpy version 1.17.0 using pip or pip3 
(assuming you already installed pip3)

```
pip3 install numpy==1.17.0
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Jetson TX2 or any other aarch64 based device. You can solve the issue by installing latest numpy and scipy libraries.

This also works for x86 based systems. (You can skip **libatlas-base-dev** and **gfortran** for x86 based systems)

```
sudo pip3 install numpy==1.19.0
sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev gfortran
sudo pip3 install scipy==1.5.1
```

Answer (score 1):

For me it solved by this [link](https://github.com/NVIDIA-AI-IOT/trt_pose_hand/issues/1#issuecomment-754248127), apparently an open issue.
Downgrade to numpy==1.16.4