# import pandas - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.testing.decorators'

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda

I'm having troubles importing pandas:

```
import pandas

--- 

In [7]: import pandas

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-7-d6ac987968b6>", line 1, in <module>
import pandas

File "//anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-    packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 56, in <module>
import pandas.util.testing

 File "//anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-  packages/pandas/util/testing.py", line 22, in <module>
from numpy.testing.decorators import slow     # noqa

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.testing.decorators'
```

I recently fully reinstalled anaconda with home-brew; moreover, I installed the following:

- pip install numpy==1.18
- pip install scipy==1.1.0
- pip install scikit-learn==0.21.3
- pip install pandas

The pandas version I'm using is 0.25.1

Does anyone have an idea of what might be going wrong?

Comment: Looks like your pandas and numpy versions are not compatible

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.testing.nosetester'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59474533/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-numpy-testing-nosetester)

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to `pandas 1.0.0` (If you have no other reason not to) via,

```
pip install -U pandas
```

See if it helps.

Comment: Usually, this happens due to NumPy version conflicts. Try to remove your current environment, create a new python environment and then install pandas first. This should install the sub dependencies correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
pip uninstall numpy
pip install numpy==1.17.0
```

Comment: This appears to be an identical answer to [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74510836/12567365) you recently provided. That may mean that the questions are duplicates - and therefore one question should be flagged as such. If the problems in the questions are not duplicates, then maybe you can differentiate your two answers?