# No module named 'numpy.testing.decorators'

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scikit-learn

Hello please I need your help :

I have python3.5 and i installed pandas

sudo apt-get install python3-pandas

then scikit learn :

sudo pip install -U scikit-learn

When I start to use :

from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

or anything related to sklearn this error appears:

No module named 'numpy.testing.decorators'

Numpy version 1.18.2
pandas version pandas==1.0.3

Comment: Installing scikit-learn from source without using conda requires you to have installed the scikit-learn Python development headers and a working C/C++ compiler with OpenMP support (typically the GCC toolchain).  I suggest that you install a separate Anaconda distribution, which already has sklearn from https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/

Comment: thank you but it is not easy for me to install anaconda now .. i have a deadline for the project

Comment: Anaconda doesn't take that long to download and install and is probably the easier way to resolve this issue, in my opinion.

Comment: thank you i will give a try .. the code  python will change in anaconda? The project must be in python

Comment: Anaconda is just a distribution of precompiled python packages.  The current distribution is for python 3.7, but your code shouldn't change because you're using the Anaconda distribution.  Also, this is just my recommendation, there may be alternate solutions to resolve your issue, but I don't personally know them.

Comment: thanks a lottt your solution works for me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.testing.nosetester'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59474533/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-numpy-testing-nosetester)

Answer (score 0):

I think the root cause of your question may stem from a dependency management conflict between two software ecosystems. Your numpy 1.18.2 was installed using pip. The pandas that depends on it was installed using apt. The versions of the two are not compatible. In fact, there is a version of numpy in the system that pandas correctly depends on, but the Python interpreter prioritizes the numpy installed by pip, leading to this issue. There are typically two solutions to this problem: (1) Use pip to uninstall numpy, and then reinstall it using apt, or uninstall pandas using apt and reinstall it using pip. (2) Use Python's imp module to customize the path and import the numpy from the apt path before importing pandas. An example is as follows:

```
import imp
path = ['/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('numpy', path)
imp.load_module("numpy", fp, pathname, description)
```

Hope my diagnosis is helpful to you！