# ImportError: No module named 'numpy.testing.nosetester'

Tags: tensorflow

I am facing an issue when I run 'from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split' in jupyter notebook.  I tried to upgrade/reinstall numpy, scipy and pandas but still cannot fix the problem.  Please help.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll have to provide some more details. Python version, target platform etc. Just check all your paths and see if you are using the same versions for Python and pip.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.testing.nosetester'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59474533/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-numpy-testing-nosetester)

Answer (score 3):

Upgrade numpy/scipy.

( Possible duplicate:
[ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.testing.nosetester'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59474533/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-numpy-testing-nosetester) )

Using Python3:

```
pip3 install numpy==1.16.4
```