# Python3: No module named 'numpy.testing.decorators' after updating numpy, scipy, and scikit-learn

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, scipy, scipy.stats

A relevant question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59474533/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-numpy-testing-nosetester). However, after I update my `numpy`, `scipy`, and `scikit-learn` packages,

```
xxx:~$ pip3 freeze | grep numpy
numpy==1.19.2
xxx:~$ pip3 freeze | grep scipy
scipy==1.5.2
xxx:~$ pip3 freeze | grep scikit-learn
scikit-learn==0.23.2
```

and run (I restart the terminal)

```
import scipy.stats as st
```

I still have the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.testing.decorators'`.

#### A comment:

This error only shows up for Python3. For Python2, it goes through.

Comment: @sophros I followed this link and upgraded each package. However, the error was still there, as I mentioned at the beginning of my question.