# Python: No module named numpy.testing.decorators for numpy 1.19.4

Tags: python, numpy, importerror

I recently updated my numpy to version 1.19.4 and my scipy to 1.5.4 when installing another new module.

I'm now getting an error message which says:

```
from numpy.testing.decorators import slow #noqa
>>> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.testing.decorators'
```

I'm not sure how to fix this. Would it have anything to do with the update?

I'm using Spyder in Anaconda

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.testing.nosetester'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59474533/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-numpy-testing-nosetester)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For numpy version `1.19.4` decorators is now under `._private`

```
from numpy.testing._private.decorators import slow
```

should work

Answer (score 0):

If you get this error in a read-only library file, you should update the library version.

For example, if you fail on `from numpy.testing.decorators import slow` in lib/python3.6/dist-packages/**pandas**/util/testing.py - you should update pandas version:

```
pip3 install -U pandas
```